# Problem related to a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]
Taking $M$ to be of the form 
\begin{pmatrix}
a &b  &c \\ 
d & e & f\\ 
 g& h & i
\end{pmatrix}  we get (from the $2$ given conditions) $6$ equations whereas total number of variables are $9$. So i think $(D)$ is the correct option.Am i going in the right direction? Please help.Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Is the vector $(6,0,0)^T$ a linear combination of the vectors $(1,2,3)^T$ and $(4,5,0)^T$? (For ease of  typing we are using $(x,y,z)^T$ for the column vector with entries $x$, $y$, and $z$.)

**Remark:** It is true that there are $9$ variables and only $6$ equations. But if the question had used, say, $(6,8,3)^T$ instead of $(6,0,0)^T$, the result *would* be determined. So simple counting of equations and unknowns is not enough.

Your suggested approach can be made to work, for example by exhibiting two solutions to the system of equations that give **different** results on $(6,0,0)^T$. This is equivalent to showing that the first *column* of the matrix $M$ is not determined.

Comment: Sir,I can not find the vector $(5,6,0)^T$ in the equations.Did you mean $(4,5,0)^T$?

Comment: @user53386: Thanks for noticing the typo. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Yours way is correct. My way of thnking goes like this : 
Since $$\pmatrix{6 \\ 0 \\ 0}=a \pmatrix{1 \\ 2 \\3}+b \pmatrix{4 \\ 5 \\0}$$ where such $a$ and $b$ do not exist, hence we cannot determine the matrix $M$

Comment: Your last $6$ was meant to be a zero?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: yeah , edited

Comment: @Idonknow thanks a lot.I have got it.+1 from me.